# What is the command to copy a file from a directory to another directory in macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line

The command that I'm trying to execute for copying a file to a directory is given below :

```
cp /Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1 /Volumes/Local Disk/Software Development/Courses/Maven/maven-learn-workspace/hello/target
```

After executing this, I'm getting this message :

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

Can anybody tell what needs to be added so that this command executes ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to protect any whitespace in the names with either `""` **or** `\`

```
cp foo 'path/with spaces/to/target'
cp foo path/with\ spaces/to/target
```

Additionally

- Using Tab Completion in `bash` and other shells will automatically insert `\` where necessary
- Drag&drop of a file/directory from Finder into a Terminal window will insert the full path of said file/directory, with appropriate escapes
- `ditto` is an alternative to `cp` which is better at handling metadata, resource forks and other specialities of macOS-specific filesystems.
- If you want/need to use environment variables as part of a path (`path/to/$TARGET/directory`), use `""` instead of `''` but look out for `$` as part of directory/file names

Comment: I thought the command prompt automatically adds quotes around the path when you press the tab key for autocompletion.

Comment: @Clockwork It does. But not everybody uses autocompletion, and it won‘t help in scripts.

Comment: You can also drag items from the Finder into a Terminal window, and it'll paste in the path with appropriate escapes.

Comment: Always protect with quotes.  I prefer single apostrophe, as it will cause less interpolation, for instance if the filename contains an environment variable.  That may be my habit of using system() from perl speaking.  I often make a variable of the quoted filename, with an if to change ' to " if the filename contains '.  I blow an exception if the filename contains both ' and ".